# how cached external javascript files helps HTML page to load fast?

Tags: javascript, html, web, caching, frontend

I am little confused on how cached external javascript file linked to HTML page  helps HTML page to load fast?
Shouldn't the internal javascript make the HTML file load faster than external javascript file?

Comment: internal and external are both relative to the html file itself. internal javascript is embedded in the html file, it's not a file. it makes the page heavier that much and you cannot cache it. the external javascript is a file and so can be cached.

Comment: @diggusbickus but how does external javascript file helps HTML file to load fast? doesn't the internal js script make the html page load fast than external?

Comment: the first time there's no difference you'll have to download all the data (html+js). starting from the second page, if the js is cached it's always faster to not download it than to download it

Answer (score 0):

Given a website with multiple HTML documents which all use the same piece of JavaScript.

If you include that JavaScript on every single page, then it has to be transferred across the network each time a page is transferred over the network.

If you link to an external JavaScript file with its own URL, then the first time a page on that site is visited then a second HTTP request has to be made to fetch the JavaScript (this is, as you pointed out in the question, slower). When *subsequent* pages are loaded, the JavaScript is fetched from the local cache instead of being transferred over the network (this is much faster).